# accordion jquery struts2 collapsable

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

Is it possible that using the sj:accordion doesn't allow other accordion items to collapse when an accordion item is selected?

Comment: Are you asking if you can have multiple accordion sections open at the same time, on purpose? If so, I don't think the default jQuery accordion supports this, so I'd assume no, but could be mistaken.

Comment: Here are some methods to do this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/accordion-multiple-sections-open-at-once none of them have anything to do with struts2 or that plugin.